# How do compare values from a previous day?

Tags: mysql, join

[The 2 Tables I'm working with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqu4y.jpg)
I am learning SQL for the first time and got the basic syntax down so I've been trying out problems on StrataScratch.

Here is the problem statement:
Each day, you have been asked to find a merchant who earned more money the previous day.
Before comparing totals between merchants, round the total amounts to the nearest 2 decimals places.
Your output should include the date in the format 'YYYY-MM-DD' and the merchant's name, but only for days where data from the previous day is available.

Note: In the case of multiple merchants having the same highest shared amount, your output should include all the names in different rows.

My code:

```
SELECT DATE(order_timestamp), merchant_details.name
FROM order_details
LEFT JOIN merchant_details
ON order_details.id = merchant_details.id
WHERE SELECT 
    (SELECT name, ROUND(total_amount_earned,2) FROM merchant_details
```

I know my code is broken and unfinished but I genuinely am not sure how I go about comparing dates dates and values at the same time. I'm pretty sure there's an AND function somewhere but don't know how to format it. I also included a photo of the tables in the link. Thank you in advance for helping a newbie out.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: From site [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc**.—copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text (no images). It is not that clear what kind of result you want.

Answer (score 0):

By using a subquery for "yesterday", and another for "today", when we join both via "inner joins" we will limit the result to only those merchants that have data for both days. It is then a relatively simple task to order the results by either of the amount columns to determine which merchant(s) have done best.

```
SELECT
      m.name AS merchant_name
    , yday.yesterday_amount_earned
    , tday.today_amount_earned
FROM merchant_details AS m
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
          o.merchant_id
        , sum(total_amount_earned) yesterday_amount_earned
    FROM order_details AS o
    WHERE (
            order_timestamp >= date_sub(CURRENT_DATE, interval 1 day)
        AND order_timestamp < CURRENT_DATE
            )
    GROUP BY
          o.merchant_id
    ) AS yday ON m.id = yday.merchant_id
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
          o.merchant_id
        , sum(total_amount_earned) today_amount_earned
    FROM order_details AS o
    WHERE (
           order_timestamp >= CURRENT_DATE
       AND order_timestamp < date_add(CURRENT_DATE, interval 1 day))
    GROUP BY
          o.merchant_id
    ) AS tday ON m.id = tday.merchant_id
ORDER BY 
      yday.yesterday_amount_earned DESC
    , tday.tday_amount_earned DESC
```